# illegal instruction (core dumped ) HElib

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gcc

I am new to HElib and I am currently testing homomorphic decryption function for AES. As a part of testing I am manually entering test values for AES key , plain text and the corresponding cipher text. I am then passing the cipher text to homomorphic decryption function to get homomorphic encryption of the plain text. This test code seemed to work fine until last morning where it errored out saying Illegal instruction ( core dumped ) when calling homomorphic decryption function. Failing to find the root cause in the test code, I tried to run Test_AES program given in the github repo and it failed to run as well. In the past when I had this issue once shutting down the VM and restarting it helped. I have tried to debug my test code but to no success. Any help in debugging this would be greatly appreciated.

```
Pasting the code here :

    uint8_t key[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
    uint8_t input[]={51,51,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48};

    uint8_t cipher[]= {201,133,214,86,19,4,199,214,206,13,152,237,236,11,241,25,108,192,10,102,210,173,131,255,215,110,154,43,202,216,154,1};


    //manually adding the test values 
    Vec<uint8_t> aesCtxt(INIT_SIZE, nBlocks16);
    Vec<uint8_t> ptxt(INIT_SIZE, nBlocks16);
    for (long i=0;i<ptxt.length();i++)
    ptxt.put(i,input[i]);

    Vec<uint8_t> aesKey(INIT_SIZE, 16); // AES-128
    for (long i=0;i<aesKey.length();i++)
    aesKey.put(i,key[i]);

    Vec<uint8_t> tmpBytes(INIT_SIZE, nBlocks*16);
    for (long i=0;i<tmpBytes.length();i++)
    tmpBytes.put(i,cipher[i]);

    cerr << " cipher = "; printState(tmpBytes);

    cout<< "going to encrypt AES key";

    vector< Ctxt > encryptedAESkey;

    hAES.encryptAESkey(encryptedAESkey, aesKey, publicKey);

    //going to homomorphically decrypt to get Homomorphic encryption of (ptxt)
    Vec encodedBytes;
    encode4AES(encodedBytes, tmpBytes, hAES.getEA()); // encode as HE plaintext

    vector< Ctxt > doublyEncrypted_AES_x;
    --------->fails here and shows Illegal instruction (core dumped ).< --------------

    // Allocate space for the output ciphertexts, initialized to zero

    doublyEncrypted_AES_x.resize(encodedBytes.length(), Ctxt(ZeroCtxtLike,encryptedAESkey[0]));

    cout<<"Dummy encrypt";

    for (long i=0; i<(long)doublyEncrypted_AES_x.size(); i++) // encode ptxt as HE ctxt

    doublyEncrypted_AES_x[i].DummyEncrypt(encodedBytes[i]);

    hAES.homAESdec(doublyEncrypted_AES_x, encryptedAESkey); // do the real work
```

Thanks in advance !

---

EDIT :
Adding Valgrind output :

```
==2653== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2653== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2653== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2653== Command: ./Test_AES_x
==2653== 
*** Test_AES: c=3, L=42, B=23, boot=0, packed=1, m=771 (=[771]), gens=[5], ords=[-32]
computing key-independent tables...done in 1.08 seconds
  27 primes (21 ctxt/6 special), total bitsize=855.929, security level: -107.015
  32 slots (2 blocks) per ctxt
computing key-dependent tables...done in 10.368 seconds
computing AES tables...ptxt length32AES key  added  input = [c9 85 d6 56 13  4 c7 d6 ce  d 98 ed ec  b f1 19 6c c0  a 66 d2 ad 83 ff d7 6e 9a 2b ca d8 9a  1 ]going to encrypt AES keyentered funcHE encodedd as plaintextcalling func 
vex amd64->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0xF3 0x4C 0xF 0x38 0xF6 0x57 0x28 0x66
vex amd64->IR:   REX=1 REX.W=1 REX.R=1 REX.X=0 REX.B=0
vex amd64->IR:   VEX=0 VEX.L=0 VEX.nVVVV=0x0 ESC=0F38
vex amd64->IR:   PFX.66=0 PFX.F2=0 PFX.F3=1
==2653== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x4e5e0f2.
==2653==    at 0x4E5E0F2: __gmpn_addmul_1 (in /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so.10.3.2)
==2653==    by 0x54F5D2: _ntl_gaorsmul_1(_ntl_gbigint_body*, long, long, _ntl_gbigint_body**) (lip.cpp:8200)
==2653==    by 0x42F7E3: MulAddTo (ZZ.h:507)
==2653==    by 0x42F7E3: operator() (DoubleCRT.cpp:730)
==2653==    by 0x42F7E3: relaxed_exec_index<DoubleCRT::toPoly(NTL::ZZX&, const IndexSet&, bool) const::__lambda5> (BasicThreadPool.h:521)
==2653==    by 0x42F7E3: DoubleCRT::toPoly(NTL::ZZX&, IndexSet const&, bool) const (DoubleCRT.cpp:741)
==2653==    by 0x431BC9: toPoly (DoubleCRT.cpp:759)
==2653==    by 0x431BC9: DoubleCRT::addPrimes(IndexSet const&) (DoubleCRT.cpp:322)
==2653==    by 0x4332D0: DoubleCRT::breakIntoDigits(std::vector<DoubleCRT, std::allocator<DoubleCRT> >&, long) const (DoubleCRT.cpp:301)
==2653==    by 0x446C05: Ctxt::keySwitchPart(CtxtPart const&, KeySwitch const&) (Ctxt.cpp:467)
==2653==    by 0x446F89: Ctxt::reLinearize(long) (Ctxt.cpp:416)
==2653==    by 0x44829D: Ctxt::smartAutomorph(long) (Ctxt.cpp:1008)
==2653==    by 0x451DB7: EncryptedArrayDerived<PA_GF2>::rotate1D(Ctxt&, long, long, bool) const (EncryptedArray.cpp:97)
==2653==    by 0x41111D: decRowShift(Ctxt&, std::vector<DoubleCRT, std::allocator<DoubleCRT> > const&, EncryptedArrayDerived<PA_GF2> const&) (homAES.cpp:713)
==2653==    by 0x4132E9: HomAES::homAESdec(std::vector<Ctxt, std::allocator<Ctxt> >&, std::vector<Ctxt, std::allocator<Ctxt> > const&) const (homAES.cpp:316)
==2653==    by 0x406567: main (Test_AES.cpp:248)
==2653== Your program just tried to execute an instruction that Valgrind
==2653== did not recognise.  There are two possible reasons for this.
==2653== 1. Your program has a bug and erroneously jumped to a non-code
==2653==    location.  If you are running Memcheck and you just saw a
==2653==    warning about a bad jump, it's probably your program's fault.
==2653== 2. The instruction is legitimate but Valgrind doesn't handle it,
==2653==    i.e. it's Valgrind's fault.  If you think this is the case or
==2653==    you are not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.
==2653== Either way, Valgrind will now raise a SIGILL signal which will
==2653== probably kill your program.
==2653== 
==2653== Process terminating with default action of signal 4 (SIGILL)
==2653==  Illegal opcode at address 0x4E5E0F2
==2653==    at 0x4E5E0F2: __gmpn_addmul_1 (in /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so.10.3.2)
==2653==    by 0x54F5D2: _ntl_gaorsmul_1(_ntl_gbigint_body*, long, long, _ntl_gbigint_body**) (lip.cpp:8200)
==2653==    by 0x42F7E3: MulAddTo (ZZ.h:507)
==2653==    by 0x42F7E3: operator() (DoubleCRT.cpp:730)
==2653==    by 0x42F7E3: relaxed_exec_index<DoubleCRT::toPoly(NTL::ZZX&, const IndexSet&, bool) const::__lambda5> (BasicThreadPool.h:521)
==2653==    by 0x42F7E3: DoubleCRT::toPoly(NTL::ZZX&, IndexSet const&, bool) const (DoubleCRT.cpp:741)
==2653==    by 0x431BC9: toPoly (DoubleCRT.cpp:759)
==2653==    by 0x431BC9: DoubleCRT::addPrimes(IndexSet const&) (DoubleCRT.cpp:322)
==2653==    by 0x4332D0: DoubleCRT::breakIntoDigits(std::vector<DoubleCRT, std::allocator<DoubleCRT> >&, long) const (DoubleCRT.cpp:301)
==2653==    by 0x446C05: Ctxt::keySwitchPart(CtxtPart const&, KeySwitch const&) (Ctxt.cpp:467)
==2653==    by 0x446F89: Ctxt::reLinearize(long) (Ctxt.cpp:416)
==2653==    by 0x44829D: Ctxt::smartAutomorph(long) (Ctxt.cpp:1008)
==2653==    by 0x451DB7: EncryptedArrayDerived<PA_GF2>::rotate1D(Ctxt&, long, long, bool) const (EncryptedArray.cpp:97)
==2653==    by 0x41111D: decRowShift(Ctxt&, std::vector<DoubleCRT, std::allocator<DoubleCRT> > const&, EncryptedArrayDerived<PA_GF2> const&) (homAES.cpp:713)
==2653==    by 0x4132E9: HomAES::homAESdec(std::vector<Ctxt, std::allocator<Ctxt> >&, std::vector<Ctxt, std::allocator<Ctxt> > const&) const (homAES.cpp:316)
==2653==    by 0x406567: main (Test_AES.cpp:248)
Dummy encryptHE dummy encrypt ==2653== 
==2653== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2653==     in use at exit: 26,478,071 bytes in 16,450 blocks
==2653==   total heap usage: 183,015 allocs, 166,565 frees, 110,651,486 bytes allocated
==2653== 
==2653== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2653==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2653==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2653==      possibly lost: 24,531,862 bytes in 9,564 blocks
==2653==    still reachable: 1,946,209 bytes in 6,886 blocks
==2653==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2653== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==2653== 
==2653== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2653== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

lscpu :

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 63
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               2394.420
BogoMIPS:              4788.84
Hypervisor vendor:     Microsoft
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              30720K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,1
```

/proc/cpuinfo

processor 0:

```
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm invpcid_single kaiser fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt
```

processor 1 :

```
 flags      : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm invpcid_single kaiser fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt`
```

Comment: What's the faulting instructions? What does `lscpu` say? What flags are shown in `/proc/cpuinfo`?

Comment: @Florian Weimer  I have added Valgrind output to my  question since it was too long to add here. Can you please let me know if you are looking for anything else for faulting instructions ?  I am adding other result to the question as well since they are long

Answer (score -1):

I got into a similar error with illegal instruction in __gmpn_addmul_1 (this is GMP library).
It was on cloud virtual pc.
A program using GMP worked all right but after restarting the VPC once I received this error. I believe the VPC processor architecture was changed for the new reboot.
I solved the problem by rebuilding the libgmp from the configure stage (when the proc arch is detected)

Comment: simply restarting does not show this issue. I think I need to do the shutdown and launch of the VPC, in this case the virtual environment could change the host